# Linear Algebra: Determine if sets Spans the same subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

In $V=C(\mathbb R)$, let:

- $S_1=\{\sin(x), \cos(x), \sin^2(x), \cos^2(x)\}$

and

- $S_2= \{1, \sin(2x), \cos(2x)\}$.

Is $\operatorname{Span}(S_1)=\operatorname{Span}(S_2)$?

---

I know that two sets of vectors in the same vector space, $S_1$ and $S_2$, span the same subspace if and only if:

Each vector in $S_1$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in $S_2$ AND
Each vector in $S_2$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in $S_1$.

I started off by creating linear combinations, but then I am stuck.

Comment: One possible thing to try: $T(f) = (f(0), f'(0), f''(0), \ldots, f^{(n)}(0))$ is a linear transformation $V \to \mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ for any $n$, so $T(\operatorname{span}(S_1)) = \operatorname{span}(T(S_1))$ and similarly for $S_2$.  And if $T(\operatorname{span}(S_1)) \ne T(\operatorname{span}(S_2))$, then obviously $\operatorname{span}(S_1) \ne \operatorname{span}(S_2)$.  So try evaluating that for some suitable value of $n$.

Comment: It might help to remind you that $\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$, so $\cos(2x)\in \text{Span}(S_1)$.  Do you remember the expression for $\sin(2x)$?  Can you **add** linear combinations of elements in $S_1$ to get $\sin(2x)$ (*multiplying functions in $S_1$ are not allowed, only adding constant multiples of them*)

Comment: Basically: use the duplication formulas for sine and cosi e

Comment: Naw dude, you can make sinx in the first subspace but not the second lll

Comment: This is a really simple question, and you really should show some real work (just claiming that you "started off by creating linear combinations" is worthless).

Answer (score 6):

Let $f(x) = a \sin x + b \cos x + c \sin^2 x + d \cos^2 x$ and
suppose $f=0$.

$f(0) = f(\pi) = 0$ and hence $b=d= 0$, $f({\pi \over2}) = f(-{\pi \over2}) = 0$ and hence $a = c = 0$.

Hence $\dim S_1 = 4$. Since $\dim S_2 \le 3$ their span cannot be equal.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) to test linear independence of functions.

The Wronskian of $(\sin(x), \cos(x), \sin^2(x), \cos^2(x), \sin(2x))$ is not zero and so $\sin(2x)$ does not belong to Span$(S_1)$. Therefore, Span$(S_1)$ $\ne$ Span$(S_2)$.

Answer (score 2):

No!

Let $\sin2x=a\sin{x}+b\cos{x}+c\sin^2x+d\cos^2x$ and take $x\in\{0,\frac{\pi}{2},\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}\}$.

You'll get $a=b=c=d=0$.

Answer (score 1):

We know $\sin 2x$ cannot be written in the desired form because, if we took the odd part of such a linear combination, we'd get something of the form $\sin 2x = a \sin x$, which cannot be an identify since the period is wrong.